# Convergence of $\sum \frac{n}{n-1}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

This is a piece of a much tougher infinite sum I'm trying to get. I think it should be a simple answer but having trouble knowing how to approach it.  Thanks for the help!

Does this sum converge?
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{n}{n-1}$$

Comment: Are you sure you wish to include n=1?

Comment: Hint: It is worth writing down some of the first few terms of this sequence. For example, $2,\frac{3}{2},\frac{4}{3},\frac{5}{4},\frac{6}{5}\dots$. You should notice that all of the terms are $\geq 1$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The series fails the divergence test; the terms don't go to zero:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{n-1} = 1\neq 0.$$
So this series does not converge.

Comment: Oops, thanks. You know how you get wrapped up in something and need to take a step back and slow down? Yeah....

Answer (score 6):

First of all, you have to change the start of that sum, since for $n=1$ you'll be dividing by $0$.

Now, we can talk about the same series, but starting from $n=2$: 
$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{n}{n-1}$

Let $(s_n)$ be the sequence that generates this series: $s_n=\frac{n}{n-1},n \geq 2$. Note that for every $n\geq 2,s_n \geq 1$, therefore:
$$
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} 1 \leq \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{n}{n-1}
$$

But the LHS diverges, therefore our series also diverges.